# Is there a way of accessing React context data in React Router 6 action function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-context

I understand hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component but I was wondering if there is a way to access context data from inside `react-router@6` action function. I have an action function that handles the user login form process. I'd like to use the `setCurrentUser` function which is coming from the app context in order  to update the state with the logged in user data returned from the API

```js
export const AuthAction = async ({ request }) => {
  const { setCurrentUser } = useAppContext()
  const data = await request.formData()
  const userData = {
    email: data.get('email'),
    password: data.get('password')
  }
  if (!userData.email || !userData.password) {
    throw json(
      { message: 'Please provide all values' },
      { status: 400, statusText: 'Please provide all values' }
    )
  }
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post('/api/auth/login', userData)
    setCurrentUser(data)
    return redirect('/')
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response.data.msg
  }
}
```

appContext.js

```
const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatchFn] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

  const setCurrentUser = (user) => {
    dispatchFn({ type: 'SET_CURRENT_USER', payload: user })
  }

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{setCurrentUser}}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}

const useAppContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext)
}

export { AppContextProvider, useAppContext }
```

I tried  getting the `setCurrentUser` function from the app context from within my action function but I get the Error: Invalid hook call. I am at a loss, I'd truly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

What I am hoping to achieve is that upon successful login, to update my app context with the current logged in user information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `AppContextProvider` component is rendered higher in the ReactTree than the `RouterProvider` component then the component rendering `RouterProvider` can access the `AppContext` value and pass it to the `authAction` function when the routes are instantaited.

Example:

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import AppContextProvider from "./app.context";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <AppContextProvider>
      <App />
    </AppContextProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

App

Update the `authAction` to curry a passed `appContext` argument and return the action function. Access `appContext` via the `useAppContext` hook and pass to the route action creator.

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  json,
  redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { useAppContext } from "./app.context";

const authAction = (appContext) => async ({ request }) => {
  const { setCurrentUser } = appContext;
  const data = await request.formData();
  const userData = {
    email: data.get("email"),
    password: data.get("password")
  };
  if (!userData.email || !userData.password) {
    throw json(
      { message: "Please provide all values" },
      { status: 400, statusText: "Please provide all values" }
    );
  }
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post("/api/auth/login", userData);
    setCurrentUser(data);
    return redirect("/");
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response.data.msg;
  }
};
```

```
export default function App() {
  const appContext = useAppContext();

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    ...
    {
      path: "/login",
      element: <Login />,
      action: authAction(appContext)
    },
    ...
  ]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

[image: Edit is-there-a-way-of-accessing-react-context-data-in-react-router-6-action-function]

Comment: Hey Drew, thank you for your help! I am just noticing that: I have to click the login button twice before the AuthAction redirects the user upon login.
On the first click of the login button I can see from the react console that the state gets updated but I have to click the button again before the user is redirected. I apologise if this is a silly oversight on my part, I am just starting off with REACT, could it be because of the async function we are returning in the AuthAction function?

Comment: @fatimaaminu Might just be a trivial oversight. Think you could create a codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue you see that we could inspect live?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your assitance Drew! while setting up the sandbox I found the bug that was causing the lag on login. I am using boostrap Nav and on login it reloads the page which  clears the state. Fixed it and all is well again!

Comment: @fatimaaminu Ah yeah, the old "react-bootstrap nav.link renders a raw anchor tag" issue. Glad you found the cause of your other issue and have it resolved. Cheers.

Comment: @DrewReese what's the equivalent of line `const authAction = (appContext) => async ({ request }) => {` in the function syntax? I tried this but it's not working: `export async function authAction({request, appContext}){`

Comment: @D.Rattansingh `const authAction = (appContext) => async ({ request }) => { ...}` is a curried function, e.g. a function that returns an asynchronous function, so your example should look something more like `export function authAction(appContext) { return async function({ request }) { ... } };`. Does this make sense?

Comment: I tried your method, it is a good method. But one thing i would like to add is you should probably use useMemo hook on your router component, because I tried without it and my action function was running multiple times.

Comment: @Verain_the_great Yes, absolutely you could/should do that as a performance optimization, if necessary. My answer here is just a barebones example.